# How to know if user has completed all tasks?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making kind of an app using only HTML, JavaScript and CSS, with several little games for kids (like puzzles, order words, draw and paint...). I have the index page with links to the pages of each game, and once the game is over, it redirects directly to the index page, all in the same browser tab.

What I would like to know is if there is some way of knowing when the player has completed one game, so after that, the game would be locked, and once the player has completed all games, it would unlock a special prize or someting.

I have tried with local storage, but the problem is that once I've played one game, it will stay locked, because the local storage keeps in memory that I have played it, even if I close the browser. Is there any way of using local storage with it "losing its memory" once you close the browser? Or is there a more efficient way than local storage?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What you are alluding to is server side persistence. You will need to have some sort of database backend if local storage and cookies do not suit your needs.

Comment: You can continue using local storage, and just change the values written to it. Or also allow someone to play the game infinite number of times, even if they have completed everything.

Comment: You are looking for SessionStorage instead of LocalStorage.

Comment: Yes but how will I know if user has played all games? What I was doing for now was, once one game was completed, I set a localStorage.game1 = 1; so in the index page I could read it. Then, if all games had been played, the sum of everything would be 10 (the number of total games) and then I would unlock the final prize, I don't know if I am making myself very clear, sorry.

Comment: once the user is playing the game you can save the session and when it ends try to delete that session, so the next time it will start refreshed

Comment: @Hec46 well if you are just checking to see if the storage sum is 10, why not just unlock the prize but still leave the game playable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good read for you : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Here is what you can do with regards to local storage :

When the page is loaded set up your local storage and set all games to `incomplete`

Create a `store()` and `check()` function to help you out and make things easier

```
function store(game, status){
    localStorage.setItem(game, status);
}
function check(game){
    return localStorage.getItem(game);
}

window.onload = function() {
    store("puzzle1", false);
    store("puzzle2", false);
    store("puzzle3", false);
}
```

As the user completes the game you can alter the data inside the storage :

```
someEvent() {
    store("puzzle1", true);
}
```

and then at the end of the game, or on your games starting page just run some checks :

```
//if puzzle1 is true
if(check("puzzle1")) {
     //do Stuff
}
```

I believe that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to use your code to experiment a little bit, if you don't mind!

Comment: @Hec46 no worries. if you have any issues just ask. Also, it seems like you could also just implement the counter like you had said earlier.

Comment: Now everything works! Thank you very much! By the way, do you know if there is some way of generating a text file with the results of each game (like number of errors, time used, etc) and emailing it to me? Because that way I could let some people try the app and then get the results of everyone by mail, with which I could do some kind of study or survey with all the data and see where I could improve the app, you know? Or is it impossible?

Comment: @Hec46 it would be easier to do this with some server side script like PHP or ASP, but it is possible without any of these if you utilize Google Forms, which I have used on several occasions. You can create a form, and then just copy the source code from the live form and put it in your page, just make it's visibility hidden and then programatically fill out the form and submit it. Just a note when programatically submitting the form, you need to change the name of google forms submit button to anything other than `submit`. If you look at my profile, it should be a question I asked previously

Comment: Thanks mate, I will look at it! Sounds interesting!

Comment: @Hec46 not a problem. If this answer was sufficient for you, if you could give me a check that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SessionStorage`. By definition "it persists in the same tab", meaning that once the page is closed, the storage is lost.

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/

Comment: Thanks for the link and the idea! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

as an example you can follow this i hope it helps you...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

try to google sessionstorage for html, there are many examples..good luck!!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will experiment with what you just gave me, see how it goes!